# .htaccess remove trailing slash

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have a htaccess file for a site to let it's script work . I don't know much about how it works, but I have to remove the trailing slash at the end.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule .* https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

ErrorDocument 404 https://www.onlinegames.nl/

## 301 Redirects
# 301 Redirect 1
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}  ^www\.onlinegames\.nl$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  ^$
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ https://www.onlinegames.nl/? [R=301,NE,NC,L]

<IfModule mod_headers.c>
  <FilesMatch "\.(ttf|ttc|otf|eot|woff|woff2|font.css|css|js)$">
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
  </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
```

How can I remove the trailing slash at the end? I've tried to change a few things, but most of the times the script is not working correctly anymore and all the subpages are not working anymore.

Comment: Removing the trailing slash, changes the folder depth of the URL path. So any relative URLs (that are not relative to the domain root), might probably need modification.

Comment: What is reason to remove the trailing slash? Can you add some examples.

Comment: I don't know much about this, but they asked me to redirect it to have just 1 version, https://www and non-trailing slash at the end.

Comment: Wht do you mean by "not working" exactly? Do all your internal links have no-trailing slash? (Your existing directives are in the wrong order. Your 404 would trigger a 302 to the homepage - this is generally bad for users and search engines?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use these rules in your site root .htaccess to replace your shown code. Note that ordering of these rules is also important and change in `ErrorDocument`.

```
ErrorDocument 404 /

RewriteEngine On

# remove www from host names
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]

# redirect http to https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]

# Unless directory, remove trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.+)/+$
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,NE,L]

# strip /index.html
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ / [R=301,NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Comment: thanks, that indeed fixed the problem. Also good to know that the ErrorDocument has to be on top.

Comment: @WouterdenOuden The ErrorDocument doesn't "have to be on top" - although it is more logical, from a readability point of view to have the error documents defined early in the file. However, the ordering of the mod_rewrite _rules_ is important.